# How do you store preferences on multilanguage apps?

Tags: java, android, localization, preferences

Lets say I save a position setting by its string `Top`.
Upon changing app language, that string becomes meaningless since in the new language it would be `Arriba` for example, and those those strings aren't equal.

So I have to store the position value `1` because it would be the same across languages.

But then the summary for the preference becomes `1` instead of whatever way "Top" is translated to in that other language.

So I map the code to the position text `1` -> `Top` for summary displaying purposes only and leave the position code alone.

I still have to translate back and forth everywhere that setting is displayed to the user (if it ever is), along with maintaining the arrays with the codes for each preference on each language and the mapping itself.

The upside is that i can use and apply the setting to the app by its code without mapping it back from its name beforehand and the fact that the app translates the code to it's string upon displaying the preferences (using the code from "Settings Activity" for that).

So I wonder, how do you manage this so it doesn't become unmanageable or comes back to bite you down the road?

Comment: If it's just a setting, why would your key change between languages. Or is it a string to be displayed in the app itself? Then it shouldnt be in the preferences anyway

Comment: Yes, it's the line that reflects the option currently selected, just below the button to select a new one on preferences screen.

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused on what you want to achieve. You store a key value pair in your shared preferences. Those shouldn't be language-specific since you program in one language only. If you want to store a currently selected index, you use an English key and put the index as a value. The text of that selected entry is localized itself with the strings.xml file. I might misunderstand you though..

Comment: No, you're right. I store the code only and I map it to its string value only when I need to display it so the user knows what's the current preference value. I just can't find a best practice about this anywhere and wonder how everyone else do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since enum are to be avoided as per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html#Abstractions), this is what i did:

Defined two arrays; one for the language string and one for the code in `arrays.xml`

```
<string-array name="lang">
    <item>Inglés</item>
    <item>Español</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="langCode">
    <item>EN</item>
    <item>ES</item>
</string-array>
```

In code I loaded both string-arrays into arrays and compared the code to obtain the language for `key`:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sp, String key) {
    Preference preference = findPreference(key);
    String arrayLang[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lang);
    String arrayCode[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.langCode);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayCode.length; i++) {
         if (arrayCode[i].contains(key)) {
             preference.setSummary(arrayLang[i]);
         }
    }
```

So now I keep `langCode` array in every language and only translate the names.

May not be the best way but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should see the problem from the opposite side. Now you are focusing on store a preference by its value but let's start from defining a type which represent all the possible values for a setting, eg:

```
enum Position
{
  TOP("position_top"),
  BOTTOM("position_bottom"),
  LEFT("position_left")
  ;

  public final String identifier;
  private Position(String identifier) { this->identifier = identifier; }
}
```

Now you have all the possible values for the setting and you associated an identifier (you could use the enum `toString()` value directly if you preferred).

This identifier can be used both for serialization in preferences both to refer a localized resource in `strings.xml`.

Comment: Nice one, didn't know it existed (I just started on Java). From further search on that i see i can put `TOP("top", 1), BOTTOM("bottom", 2)`, etc. to reference back and forth, right?.

Comment: Sure, but using a number to serialize a key/value pair doesn't make sense when you can use a meaningful string for it.